# Case conditions not working in apex calendar and sql develover

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

The conditions i create in case doesnt affect the apex calendar as they should this conditions are for workshifts that im creating in apex calendar.
Can someone help me it this conditions?

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE                                    check_task_turnos AS
    BEGIN
    FOR i IN (SELECT ID, calendar_start, calendar_end, estado, TIPO,
    ,CASE
    when to_number(to_char(calendar_start,'DD')) = to_number(to_char(sysdate,'DD'))
    AND to_number(to_char(calendar_start,'HH24')) >= 7 AND to_number(to_char(calendar_end,'HH24')) < 15   
    AND to_number(to_char(sysdate,'HH24')) >= 7    AND to_number(to_char(sysdate,'HH24')) >= 15 
    then 'apex-cal-yellow'
    when to_number(to_char(calendar_start,'DD')) = to_number(to_char(sysdate,'DD'))
    AND to_number(to_char(calendar_start,'HH24')) >= 15 AND to_number(to_char(calendar_end,'HH24')) < 23   
    AND to_number(to_char(sysdate,'HH24')) >= 15    AND to_number(to_char(sysdate,'HH24')) >= 23 
    then 'apex-cal-yellow'
    when to_number(to_char(calendar_start,'DD')) = to_number(to_char(sysdate,'DD'))
    AND to_number(to_char(calendar_start,'HH24')) >= 23 AND to_number(to_char(calendar_end,'HH24')) < 7   
    AND to_number(to_char(sysdate,'HH24')) >= 23    AND to_number(to_char(sysdate,'HH24')) >= 7 
    then 'apex-cal-yellow'
    else null  end
    FROM PASSAGEM
    where estado='Aceite'
    and TIPO='To Do'
    )

          LOOP
        -- registo no LOG , aqui nao registas na PASSAGEM, registas numa tabela ao lado de LOG para teres referencia de quando foi alterada a data da tarefa
                    INSERT INTO PASSAGEM_LOG(passagem_id,
                                            start_date,
                                            end_date   
                                            )
                                    VALUES(i.id ,  
                                            i.calendar_start+( 8/24) ,
                                          i.calendar_end +(8/24));
                 -- update das horas de inico e fim para posicionamento no calendario
                    UPDATE PASSAGEM
                    SET  calendar_start = i.calendar_start+(8/24) --incrementamos 8horas (periodod e um turno
                        ,calendar_end   = i.calendar_end+(8/24) --incrementamos 8horas (periodod e um turno
                    WHERE ID = i.ID;
                                END LOOP;
                               COMMIT;
                              END;
```

Comment: Case conditions working or not working?

Comment: the case condtions they don´t work, how can i resolve this

Comment: What is “Not working”? The code won’t compile, runs with error, does nothing, does something different? How do you  change an Apex calendar display anyway? I don’t see any code to change anything in your question.

Comment: this code what it does every time that runs adds 8 hours calendar_star and 8 hours to claendar_end and moves the blocks in apex calendar but should only do that when workshift ends like between 7 and 15 o'clock

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: I don't know Apex. What is the code for changing a calendar display? All your code does is insert a log record and update a table, which it does without any `CASE` expression, so I don't know what you are trying to do or what it has to do with Apex or SQL Developer.

Comment: code is for updating the apex calendar automatically  every time a work shift ended or a work shift opens a case is for creating restrictions for the work shift ends and starts in that particular hours

Comment: So does your update of `passagem` do that? Nobody here knows how your application works. You need to describe a specific technical issue before anyone can help you. I’m voting to close because there is no technical question to answer.

Comment: yes, the update passagem, is the table create for apex calendar

Answer (score 1):

You should really learn how to properly format code; the one you posted is difficult to read and understand.

As of your question: this procedure uses a cursor `FOR` loop. That long, ugly `CASE`

- doesn't have an alias
- is never used later in procedure code

  - if you plan to use it, set its alias (e.g. `my_case`) so that you could reference it as `i.my_case`

So, why do you expect it to do *anything*, anywhere? The way it is now, as if `CASE` was never written.

Comment: if i put cursor how do implement the conditions that are implement in the case